# Can we handle Exception while executing Update in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I want to update some 34000 records in a table. take an sample of query below

```
UPDATE table_X 
   SET status='Y' 
WHERE ACCTID IN (SELECT acctid FROM ACCOUNTS) 
AND status !='Y';
```

there is primary key constraint on group of columns at table `table_x`. Can I have any solution like update in Cursor or anything which escape that particular record which violates primary key constraint?

Comment: You should be able to build that check into the SQL statement. If you describe the situation more fully I expect someone will give you the code to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can handle the exception for each row, with the code below:

```
BEGIN
FOR i IN (SELECT acctid FROM ACCOUNTS) LOOP
    BEGIN
        UPDATE table_X 
           SET status='Y' 
        WHERE ACCTID = i.acctid
        AND status !='Y';
    EXCEPTION 
        WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
            --HANDLE THE EXCEPTION
            DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_Line( 'Handle the exception' );  
    END;
END LOOP;
END;
```

You can also, create a cursor, and iterate over it.

If your update could be over a lot of rows, you'd want to use forall, bulk collect and limit. Because a big update can use a lot of undo space, and you need to perform a commit every group of rows updated to prevent this. You can catch and handle exceptions for every row as well in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

As with any data analysis task this one will involve some manual problem solving. I can see why the update statement fails in your example. It looks like you have a primary key on ACCTID and STATUS columns. In your situation you have an account with two status rows one of each is already set to Y. Imagine this situation:

```
table_x:
ACCTID    STATUS
12345      N
12345      Y
```

First of all, if you have a table with design like this it is most likely a design flaw. If you allow only one status row per account then the Index should be on ACCTID column only (unless of course there is another column, like DateAdded, that is also part of the primary key). However, we all know, that sometimes we just need to deal with those situations.

To fix your problem you have two options:

1. Run DELETE statement before your update to delete the entries that have STATUS 'Y' and not 'Y' for the same ACCTID leaving only the 'Y' status. The statement will look something like this:

   ```
   DELETE FROM table_x
   WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                FROM table_x a 
                WHERE a.ACCTID=table_x.ACCTID 
                GROUP BY ACCTID 
                HAVING count(STATUS) > 1) 
   AND status <> 'Y'
   ```

After you delete the duplicate entries you can execute the Update statement of yours

1. Modify your UPDATE statement to be more smart, like this:

   ```
   UPDATE table_X 
   SET status='Y' 
   WHERE ACCTID IN (SELECT acctid FROM ACCOUNTS) 
     AND status !='Y'
     AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                    FROM table_x a 
                    WHERE a.ACCTID=table_x.ACCTID 
                    AND status='Y');
   ```

Disclaimer: as with all update/delete statements make sure you have a fresh backup.